# How to run python on a Godaddy shared server with cpanel?

Tags: php, python, django, cpanel, shared-hosting

Let me start off by saying that I know this is not the preferred way to run python, but I have had this website for several years and am looking to add additional functionality. If I try to move the site to a new host and server setup, I am afraid I will mess everything up.

I am using Godaddy shared server for my website, and I access it using cpanel. The website is a Wordpress blog but also has a few tools I built using PHP and SQL database to store the output. I want to create a chatbot using Python but from what I understand, I can't use Django on a shared Godaddy server.

Is there a way for me to run Python scripts given my limitations?

Is the best alternative for me to start a second server and build an API to process the conversation and send it back to my current website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared hosting solutions tend to limit the software that can run on then. The last time I used GoDaddy, they had only a php stack, so probably no, you won't be able to use Python there. 
But that's fine, you shouldn't! 
If you plan on using Python, I recommend you to get a Vps, or switch to a cloud service, like Openshift.
You can find cheap and reliable Vps servers nowadays, so go for it.